# How to force to reinstall pip

Tags: python-3.x, centos, pip

I'm using CentOS 6.5 on a remote server with python2.6, python2.7.6 & python3.4.0

some of you may know that CentOS only have python2.6 & yum needs that

python 2.7/3.4 are for project I'm currently working on.

I installed pip with python2.7 before, and today I need pip in python3 so I do the following:

`python3 get-pip.py`

but pip still install packages in 2.7 and there is no method called `pip3` for me

so I dicided to remove pip and install it again, found that `python3 get-pip.py` just not working, saying pip is already installed and works fine.

then I did some stupid things:

`rm -rf $py3_home/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip`

`rm -rf /usr/bin/pip*`

the `get-pip.py` still believe it's installed and quit

How to fix pip now?